# Prometheus Alertmanager, group_interval and reapeat_interval doesn't work

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I configured prometheus alertmanager to group alerts by label `memory`, wait for `1m` to collect all alerts for this group then send all this group's alerts to receiver. Also, I want alertmanager to wait `1d` before sending new alert which includes current firing alerts and new alerts in this group. But my configuration doesn't work propetly.

Here it is:

```
route:
  receiver: telegram_tech
  group_by:
  - memory
  continue: false
  routes:
  - receiver: telegram_configs
    match:
      route: configs
    continue: false
  - match:
      route: networks
    continue: false
    routes:
    - receiver: telegram_tech
      continue: true
    - receiver: sms
      continue: false
  group_wait: 1m
  group_interval: 1d
  repeat_interval: 1d
```

With this configuration I receive alerts at different intervals, from several minutes till more than 1 day.
Could you please tell me what I do wrong?